# Scala error: value sort is not a member of List

Tags: list, scala, sorting

Following a simple example at http://www.simplyscala.com/ I get:

```
scala> val lst=List(1,7,2,8,5,6,3,9,14,12,4,10)
lst: List[Int] = List(1, 7, 2, 8, 5, 6, 3, 9, 14, 12, 4, 10)

scala> lst.sort(_>_)
<console>:9: error: value sort is not a member of List[Int]
      lst.sort(_>_)
```

What is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SimplyScala wasn't updated for a long long time: [.sort was deprecated](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L310) in 2.8.0 and cut out in latter versions. Instead you have to use `sortWith` method.

Answer (score 2):

`sort`is actually not defined in class [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). You should use `sortWith` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running new version such as scala 2.11.8, you should check the document here [scala 2.11.8 lib API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#package).

Comment: Search List, you will get three options for sort:
sortBy, sortWith and sorted.